# How can i winsorize a monthly sample by its cumulative Market Volume in each month?

Tags: r, rank

Following http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~lpederse/papers/ValMomEverywhere.pdf
(page 933 bottom), i want to restrict my monthly data only to the firms which have a market capitalization of 90% together. 
So for each month i need to rank my stocks by their beginning of month market volume. This wouldn't be a problem i guess since the sort function would do it. 
Then i have to order them in descending order and only include stocks, which cumulative account for 90% of the stock markets market cap. 
So i need to calculate the total market cap for each month:

```
Marketcap<-rowSums(Volume.Monthly,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Sort them in increasing order:

```
help.variable<-sort(Volume.Monthly[i,],decreasing = FALSE)
```

Divide them by their Market cap

```
q<-help.variable/Marketcap[i]
```

perform cumsum

```
cumsum(q)
```

and replace every value below 0.9 with NA

But how can i do that for a sample with 300+ Months and still remain the structure (Apple in column 1, AMZ in column 2 etc), so that in every row(for every date), where the firm (in columns) isn't part of the top 90% market cap firms, is a NA ?

Thank you very much for every input !

**EDIT**

Implying this is my data set 
     V.M<-(matrix(c(3,1,5,2,6,5,7,8,9,19,17,2,4,9,11),nrow=5,ncol=3))

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5   17
[2,]    1    7    2
[3,]    5    8    4
[4,]    2    9    9
[5,]    6   19   11
```

This would be my total Marketvolume for each row(date)

```
Mcap<-rowSums(V.M)
```

V.M/Mcap gives:

```
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.1200000 0.2000000 0.6800000
[2,] 0.1000000 0.7000000 0.2000000
[3,] 0.2941176 0.4705882 0.2352941
[4,] 0.1000000 0.4500000 0.4500000
[5,] 0.1666667 0.5277778 0.3055556

ö<-V.M/Mcap
```

Which would be the percentage Marketshare of each stock at each month (row)

Now i want to include only the biggest stocks, which have together 50% (chose wrong numbers for my example) of the market cap.

So i would need to

```
q<-foreach(i=1:5,.combine = rbind) %do%
+     sort(ö[i,])
```

Which yields to:

```
             [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
result.1 0.1200000 0.2000000 0.6800000
result.2 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.7000000
result.3 0.2352941 0.2941176 0.4705882
result.4 0.1000000 0.4500000 0.4500000
result.5 0.1666667 0.3055556 0.5277778
```

now cumsum:

```
e<-foreach(i=1:5,.combine = rbind) %do%
+     cumsum(q[i,])


            [,1]      [,2] [,3]
result.1 0.1200000 0.3200000    1
result.2 0.1000000 0.3000000    1
result.3 0.2352941 0.5294118    1
result.4 0.1000000 0.5500000    1
result.5 0.1666667 0.4722222    1
```

Which would be the criteria for my initial data, every stock which isn't part of the largest stocks who have a cumulative market cap of 50% or bigger (Yes in my question it was 90% but i f'd up my example) should be excluded.

So the Output of my input data should be

```
     [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,]     NA       NA     0.6800000
[2,]     NA     0.7000000    NA
[3,] 0.2941176 0.4705882     NA
[4,]     NA    0.4500000 0.4500000
[5,]     NA     0.5277778     NA
```

Obviously because of  the sorting, my initial structure changed.

Every helpful advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and expected result?

Comment: added an example !